# WSO2 ESB Javascript replace with regular expressions

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to use the replace function of a javascript String with a regular expression as the first argument. It causes an error because the parameter does not fix the replace arguments (char, char). The sentence is:

```
prop = prop.replace(/'/g,"");
```

I test the instruction in chrome javascript console and it works as expected. The problem seems to be that the javascript version wso2 uses does not implement this feature.

Any help?

Comment: What's the error you get? What version of ESB are you trying?

Comment: The error was that I was not using the right constructor so the regular expression was not wrapped by quotes. I finally realised that the "replace" function is a replaceAll one, since what I was trying to do with regular a regular expression was archived without any regular expression, just typing prop.replace("'","").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve a better productivity with javascript, it is recommended to use the script mediator to do your javascript validations in WSO2 ESB. You can use inline javascript codes as well as to save the javascirpt in registry and re-use when necessary. Please refer to the following link [1] for more details on how to implement the script mediator using WSO2 ESB.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Script+Mediator

Regards,
Pubudu.